# Open link on default browser instead of webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, external

I have the code below but I need to open all links on external browser and not on the webview, how to do this?

```
twitter = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        twitter.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        twitter.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        twitter.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.web_url));
        twitter.refreshDrawableState();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `WebView` to open a browser, use an `Intent`, like this:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Ok but I only need to change my sample code to this new and will work?

Comment: @user1505698 yes